# How to specify exceptions from wildcard settings in a logrotate configuration file?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, logrotate

For my logfiles I have the problem of all but one (or a few) files use the same configuration, while the rest has another one. I tried to realize this by giving a general configuration for all files and then overwriting this configuration for the few specific files later, e.g.:

```
/var/log/mylogs/*.log {
                   size 1000k
                   copytruncate
                   create 0644 root root
                   rotate 99
                   compress
                   missingok
}

/var/log/mylogs/thatonespecial.log {
                   size 1000k
                   copytruncate
                   create 0644 myuser mygroup
                   rotate 99
                   compress
                   missingok
}
```

However, this raises an error:

```
error: /var/log/mylogs/logrotate.conf:10 duplicate log entry for /var/log/mylogs/thatonespecial.log
```

How should I handle such a situation properly? I certainly don't want to list the large number of standard log files individually, so the use of the wildcard configuration seems reasonable to me. But how can I then specify an exception among the wildcarded files?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most elegant answer is to put `thatonespecial.log` in a separate directory so it wouldn't be able to match the wildcard.

If that won't work, then you can use [globs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) to narrow down your wildcard.  It's messy, but if you absolutely can't move the file location then it's probably your only real option.  Something like this:

```
/var/log/mylogs/[!t][!h]*.log
```

Would match any .log files with at least 2 characters in their name that don't start with "th".

Comment: This doesn't work as expected. Filename `that.log` will be ignored, but filename `txxx.log` will be ignored as well. For some reason the `[!h]` part is not playing any role. As soon as a file starts with `t`, then it'll be ignored.

Comment: this not work in example `/var/log/nginx/[!access].log` the error.log not rotate but access.log rotate in another configure below

Answer (score 9):

It seems that the overwriting of rules was implemented and it works now:

```
$ logrotate --version
logrotate 3.8.7

$ cat /etc/logrotate.d/test
# rotate application logs for 40 days by default
/home/myapp/log/*.log
/home/myapp/log/*/*.log
{
    daily
    compress
    delaycompress
    rotate 40
}

# rotate access logs for 1 year
/home/myapp/log/access/*.log {
    daily
    compress
    delaycompress
    rotate 365
}

$ logrotate  -d /etc/logrotate.d/test
reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/test

Handling 2 logs

rotating pattern: /home/myapp/log/*.log
/home/myapp/log/*/*.log
 after 1 days (40 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
No logs found. Rotation not needed.

rotating pattern: /home/myapp/log/access/*.log  after 1 days (365 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
No logs found. Rotation not needed.
```

While when tested on my local logrotate (version 3.7.8) the error was raised:

```
$ cat logr.conf 
# rotate application logs for 40 days by default
/home/myapp/log/*.log
/home/myapp/log/*/*.log
{
    daily
    compress
    delaycompress
    rotate 40
}

# rotate access logs for 1 year
/home/myapp/log/access/*.log {
    daily
    compress
    delaycompress
    rotate 365
}

$ logrotate -d logr.conf 
reading config file logr.conf
reading config info for /home/myapp/log/*.log
/home/myapp/log/*/*.log

error: logr.conf:12 duplicate log entry for /home/myapp/log/access/api_access.log
error: found error in /home/myapp/log/access/*.log , skipping
removing last 1 log configs

...
```

Comment: Very nice. I want to emphasize one thing because it's a bit counter-intuitive: the man page states: "later definitions override earlier ones." Your example is correct; I'm just saying this because I had expected the opposite would have been the case.

Comment: This doesn't work for me using `logrotate 3.13.0` distributed as an alpine package. Different implementation perhaps...

Comment: Same error here with `logrotate 3.18.0` from Debian 11.5 Bullseye: `duplicate log entry for...`

Answer (score 2):

If you know the names of all logs, you could also specify them together in one rule:

```
/var/log/mylogs/{file1,file2,file3,file4,file5}.log {
    size 1000k
    copytruncate
    create 0644 root root
    rotate 99
    compress
    missingok
}

/var/log/mylogs/thatonespecial.log {
    size 1000k
    copytruncate
    create 0644 myuser mygroup
    rotate 99
    compress
    missingok
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thks **Hyppy**
I had the same issue here and Your solution ([!x][!y]*.log) worked just fine
I tried to vote your answer as usefull, but still i have not enough reputation
:(
So, here is my thk you

And for **flourigh**, in your config ( [!access] )
keep in mind that all characters inside the brackets is for catch one sigle character, so your config will catch only files NOT (!) beggining with a, c, e & s only (first char only, ok?)
good reference here: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/en/man7/glob.7.html
(on complementation paragraph)

You should expand it to [!a][!c][!c][!e].... or find another way to aim that file only

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/572189)